# Robot OOP Class in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented

**Hello everyone!**

Here is the thing. So I wanted at first to create Robot class, I want him to move around some board. Maybe 10x10 or something like that, then i wanted to invent a Robot fights class, I want to add class players (becuase i want to play between player 1 and player 2) but here it is what I have so much.

Lets focus on this code because I want it to make it much better then start to create robot fights!

```py
class Robot:

    def __init__(self, name, place, start = (0,0), power = 9):
        self.name = name
        self.start = start
        self.place = place
        self.power = power
        
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
        
    def get_start(self):
        return self.start
        
    def get_place(self):
        return self.place
        
    def get_power(self):
        return self.power
        

    
    def set_name(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, str):
            self.name = x
        else:
            raise TypeError("must be a string")
    
    def set_start(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, tuple):
            self.start = x
        else:
            raise TypeError("must be a tuple")
    
    def set_place(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            self.place = x
        else:
            raise TypeError("must be a list")
    
    def set_power(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, int):
            self.power = x
        else:
            raise TypeError("must a int")
    
    
    
    def check_power(self):
        if self.power <= 0:
            raise ValueError("No power")
            
          
    def left(self, value):
        self.check_power()
        
        self.power -= value

        if self.place[0] - value < 0:
            self.place[0] = self.place[0] - value + 8

        else:
            self.place[0] = self.place[0] - value
            
    def up(self, value):
        self.check_power()
        
        self.power -= value

        if self.place[1] + value > 7:
            self.place[1] = self.place[1] + value - 8

        else:
            self.place[1] = self.place[1] + value

        if self.place[1] == 5:
            self.power += 2

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name, self.place, self.power
```

Also want I want to make better in this one. Well power will be important in the Robot fights, because if some robot from player 1 will be near to robot from player 2 I want them to you know, fight, so the power will be pretty good right there, if they will be near to each other the power will decrease until the robot is destroyed. But lets focus on above code to make it better.

Any tips how to make this SHORTER and more neat, closer to a advanced or just better solution will be definitely on point.

**Have a great day!**

Answer (score 1):

**Type annotations**

Using type annotations will make your program a lot more readable and easier to debug. For example:

```
def __init__(self, name, place, start = (0,0), power = 9):
    # assignments
```

becomes

```
def __init__(self, name: str, place : List[int], start: Tuple[int, int] = (0,0), power: int = 9):
    # assignments
```

I imported `List, Tuple` from the `typing` module from the standard library:

```
from typing import List, Tuple
```

[Here's some further information on using type annotations.](https://dev.to/dstarner/using-pythons-type-annotations-4cfe)

---

**Getter and Setter**

Using getters and setters is rather unpythonic. You can instead modify the getting and setting behaviours by using the `@property` decorator like this:

```
def __init__(self, name: str, place : List[int], start: Tuple[int, int] = (0,0), power: int = 9):
    self._name = name

    # further assignments

@property
def name(self):
    return self._name

@name.setter
def name(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        self._name = value
    else:
        raise TypeError("must be a string")
```

This will allow you to use the properties without explicitly calling getter and setter methods:

```
my_robot.name = 'foo'
print(my_robot.name)
```

[This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627002/9173379) contains some more detailed explanations.

---

**Logic**

1. You should also take a look at your setters for `place` and `start`.
   You only check the type of the passed argument `value`, but do not
   verify if the elements in the `list` or `tuple` are of type `int`.
2. You could consider using a custom class `Position` or similiar for
   handling the positional logic of the robot. That way you can access
   the different dimensions by their names instead of indices of
   `place` (`self.place[0]` or `self.place[1]`). You'll also be able to put further logic (like clipping, etc.) into it.
3. `power` and `check_power()`: Depending on your intended functionality you might want to limit the number of steps that can be taken by a robot to the `power` that it has left. As it is now, a robot can take any number of steps as long as it has `power > 0` left.
4. You should check the functionality `left(value)` and `up(value)` for big values, especially values that are `> 2 * board_dimension`. I suspect the results might be unintended.

Comment: Overall agreed. I would take your "unpythonic accessor functions" further - if there is any kind of non-trivial logic to the get or set, `@property` is called for, but here it isn't. Just make a "public" variable.

Comment: Genuine question: How do you then verify / ensure that only values of a certain type are assigned to *public* attributes, if at all?

Comment: The short answer is that you don't. Type verification - typically - is not done at all, since Python uses duck typing. Recent support for static analysis of types is helpful but doesn't apply in runtime.

If you do want to apply validation to a value before set, then you would do it as you've shown with `@properties` or - if you're able to make the class immutable, which has a lot of advantages - then during `__init__`.